# C# does generic contain empty collection

Tags: asp.net, caching, collections, null, protobuff.net

An annoying behaviour of ProtoBuff.net is that empty collections are serialised as `null`.  This can create some pretty hard to pin down bugs.

Retrieval of cached values from my application is done with the following function:

```
public T Get<T>(string cacheKey)
{
    var data = (byte[])Database.StringGet(cacheKey);
    if (data == null)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    return Serialiser.Deserialise<T>(data);
}
```

If `T` is `List<int>` with zero values, this will return an empty list (because `data == null` it will return `default(List<int>)`).

If `T` is `Dictionary<bool, Hashset<int>`, where two keys `true` and `false` exist but there are no values in the corresponding hashset, the key exists but the value is `null`.

Is there any way to determine if `T` **contains** a collection, and if so return an empty collection instead of null if the collection is empty?  Preferably, it would check for an empty collection anywhere in the object, not just if T itself is a collection that contains a collection.

The alternative (that I'm doing now) is to try to remember to check for nulls when I know the explicit type when I get from cache which isn't ideal.

Comment: Do you know the type you're expecting when you call Get?  If so have an overload for this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use typeof operator.

```
if(typeof(T)== typeof(Dictioneary))
{
  return whatever you want;
}
```

Comment: I'm after a more general approach that covers all cases

Comment: It helps if you will provide the default value as second argument to your method.

Comment: Like 'public T Get<T>(string cacheKey, T defaultValue)'

Comment: Doesn't help as you don't know if a collection property of T is empty or not

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, would something like this help?

```
void Main()
{
    Get<int>("cacheKey1").Dump();
    Get<List<string>, string>("cacheKey2").Dump();
    Get<Dictionary<string, string>, KeyValuePair<string,string>>("cacheKey3").Dump();
}

public T Get<T>(string cacheKey)
{
    ...
    return default(T);
}

public IEnumerable<S> Get<T, S>(string cacheKey) where T : IEnumerable<S>
{
    ...
    return Enumerable.Empty<S>();
}
```